# Get catalina_opts in java

Tags: java, tomcat

How can I get all the `CATALINA_OPTS` and/or `JAVA_OPTS` parameters in a Java web app?

I know I can read `System.getProperties()` to get all the system properties. However, it will just show all system properties, including the `-D` parameters passed via `CATALINA_OPTS`. Not any parameters like `-Xmx`, `-Xms`, etc.

I know I can read `ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean()` to get all the Java parameters. However, this also shows just the `-D` parameters. Not any parameters like `-Xmx`, `-Xms`, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Environment variables can usually be accessed through System.getenv():

```
String javaOpts = System.getenv("JAVA_OPTS"); // gets one value
Map<String, String> all = System.getenv(); // gets all the environment strings
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question, you can use [`System.getenv(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv%28java.lang.String%29) like so

```
String catalinaOpts = System.getenv("CATALINA_OPTS");
String javaOpts = System.getenv("JAVA_OPTS");
System.out.printf("JAVA_OPTS = %s CATALINA_OPTS = %s%n", javaOpts, catalinaOpts);
```